# CommandLineRunner run() method is not being called

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have tried all the answers provided on this platform but didn't work. I am executing this command line runner but the run method is not calling.

I appricaite for your help.

Thanks.

[image: MyCommandlineRunner class]

[image]

I have tried below solution but got this exception.

1st: at your Bootstrap class (the class which has the main method with SpringApplication.run(..., args)), you can add the attribute scanBasePackages at the @SpringBootApplication annotation:

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.project.data.runner"})
This will tell Spring to look for components, also, at the com.project.data.runner package.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Bootstrap class is on the package `com.project.demo.data`

Your command line runner is on the package `com.project.data.runner`

Spring will scan for components in the sub-packages of `com.project.demo.data`, that is, in `com.project.demo.data.*`, that's why your command line runner is never ran. He's never found by Spring.

You have some options, but I'll state two:

**1st**: at your Bootstrap class (the class which has the `main` method with `SpringApplication.run(..., args)`), you can add the attribute `scanBasePackages` at the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.project.data.runner"})
```

This will tell Spring to look for components, also, at the `com.project.data.runner` package.

**OR**

**2nd**: move your command line runner from `com.project.data.runner` to `com.project.demo.data.runner` (or something similar that is under `com.project.demo.data`)

**UPDATE**

*As we've solved the problem in the chat, I'll update the answer with the solution.*

Since you're using Spring Data JPA Repositories, if your repositories are not under the package or sub-packages where your Bootstrap class resides, then you must add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to a `@Configuration` class and explicitly configure on which package your repository is.

Your bootstrap class will look like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.project.data.runner"})
@Configuration
@EntityScan("com.project.data.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.project.data.repository" })
public class DataJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matheus,

I have tried 1st solution but got that exception. I have attached the screen shot.

Comment: And have tried 2nd one but haven't worked.

Comment: In which package is your `PassangerRepository`?

Comment: It is in "com.project.data.repository" package

Comment: Then, add the other package to the scanBasePackages attribute: `scanBasePackages = {"com.project.data.runner", "com.project.data.repository"}`

Comment: Still getting the same exception

Comment: Is your repository annotated?

Comment: Yes with @Repository annotation

Comment: Strange... I know it may sound dumb, but try changing the order of the packages in the scanBasePackages attribute. First, add the repository package, then add the runner package: `scanBasePackages = {"com.project.data.repository", "com.project.data.runner"}`

Comment: I have changed order but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230465/discussion-between-naresh-and-matheus-cirillo).

Comment: Any other solutions Matheus?

Comment: Let's go to the chat, I've tested out and it worked properly here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the fix was to add @Component to the class definition.